# Delete empty rows in comment in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for a way to delete empty rows in comments using VBA. I have an Excel file with loads of corrupted comments, containing empty rows, and going through them one by one is not an option.

I haven't identified a command for editing rows in comments, and don't know where to start, so I don't have any code to show you guys. But I'm thinking in the line of:

```
For Each comment In ActiveSheet.Comments
    "REMOVE EMPTY ROWS" <-- What to put here?
Next comment
```

Hope that you can help me anyway!

EDIT:
All my empty lines are at the end of the comment like this:

[image]

Comment: There are lots of readymade code available for this on google. Did you try to google ?

Comment: Of course I tried Google! But I didn't find anything,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. It seems that it's not empty rows, it's just the size of the comment that was changed somehow. So this code fixed it:

```
Sub Comments_AutoSize()

Dim MyComments As Comment
Dim lArea As Long
For Each MyComments In ActiveSheet.Comments
  With MyComments
    .Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    If .Shape.Width > 300 Then
      lArea = .Shape.Width * .Shape.Height
      .Shape.Width = 200
      .Shape.Height = (lArea / 200) * 1.1
    End If
  End With
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your comment looks like this

[image]

You could try this

```
Sub RemoveEmptyLinesInComments()

    Dim c As Comment
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Comments
        c.Text Text:=Replace(c.Text, vbLf, Chr(32))
    Next c

End Sub
```

to achieve

[image]

## Update

Ok, after you've edited your question and changed the meaning with the provided details Ive come up with another code as a solution. Try

```
Sub RemoveEmptiesFromComments()

    Dim c As Comment
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Comments
        Dim v As Variant
        v = Split(c.Text, Chr(32))
        Dim i As Long, s As String
        For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v) - 1
            s = s & Chr(32) & v(i)
        Next i
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = c.Parent
        c.Delete
        rng.AddComment Text:=s
        rng.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, didn't get that to work. All my empty lines are at the end of the comment, see my edited question above, does that matter?